# Calling button actions in segmented control

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a segmented control action method with two segments

```
@IBAction func segmentChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) { 

    // What goes here for displaying data similar to buttonsTapped? 
}
```

I have three buttons as follows

```
 @IBOutlet weak var buttonOne: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet weak var buttonTwo: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet weak var buttonThree: UIButton!
```

I have an action method for all 3 buttons,

```
 @IBAction func buttonsTapped(_ sender: UIButton) { 

    switch sender {
    case buttonOne:
     print("Button one Tapped")
    case buttonTwo:
     print("Button two tapped")
    case buttonThree:
     print("Button three tapped")
    default: break
    }

  if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0
        {
            print("First Segment")
        }
        else
        {
            print("Second Segment")
        }
  }
```

When I tap on buttonOne, I am getting `"First Segment"` and `"Button One Tapped"` as it is in the first segment. Similarly, buttonTwo and buttonThree, are displaying correct messages on the console.

But when I am changing the segmented control, I am not getting any messages on the console. I tried by calling `buttonOne.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)` in `segmentChanged` method and it works only for buttonOne and messes up others. How do I get proper messages for all buttons and segments when the segment is changed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex code need to placed in segmentChanged and not in buttonsTapped if nothing changed in segmentedControl then selectedSegmentIndex will be Zero

Comment: Well, I want the data to be printed on the console from both the segmented changed and button tapped methods.

Comment: @Coder221 - you want to perform this one in button action or else

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Yes, in button action from segmented control as well or is there any way better to display the data from both ends?

Comment: yes we can do...

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, can you please answer it then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set your `UISegmentedControl` method for `.valueChange` not for `.touchUpInside`.

Looks following:

[image: UISegmentedControl]

and add following method.

**Code:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var buttonOne            : UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var buttonTwo            : UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var buttonThree          : UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl     : UISegmentedControl!

var selectedButton                      : UIButton!

@IBAction func buttonsTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    selectedButton = sender

    switch sender {

    case buttonOne:
        print("Button one Tapped")

    case buttonTwo:
        print("Button two tapped")

    case buttonThree:
        print("Button three tapped")

    default: break
    }

    if self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        print("First Segment")
    } else {
        print("Second Segment")
    }
}


@IBAction func segmentChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0
    {
        self.selectedButton.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    else
    {
        self.selectedButton.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}
```

Comment: It was set up for .valueChange

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/n1xNBdl . I am trying to get same data from both button and segmented controls. Hope, my question was clear.

Comment: @Coder221, It's okay, then What happening ?

Comment: Share the demo project.

Comment: How do I get "First segment" and "Button one Tapped" together when I click on First segmented control and similarly "First segment" and "Button Two Tapped", "First segment" and "Button Three Tapped"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194687/discussion-between-mayur-karmur-and-coder221).

Answer (score 1):

Segment Control value changed will log by using below method

```
   @IBAction func segmentChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) { 
    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0
            {
                print("First Segment")
            }
            else
            {
                print("Second Segment")
            }
    }
```

And Button Action will be logged using below method:

```
@IBAction func buttonsTapped(_ sender: UIButton) { 

    switch sender {

    case buttonOne:
     print("Button one Tapped")
    case buttonTwo:
     print("Button two tapped")
    case buttonThree:
     print("Button three tapped")
    default: break
    }
}
```

Both methods can't be combined because button associated to touch-up inside event and segmented control is associated with value changed event

Comment: I am trying to display data from both the ends. I successfully made it work in buttonsTapped as described in the question. I was partially successful for segmentChanged method as mentioned above by calling .touchUpInside for one button and got confused on how to implement for remaining two buttons.